# Visual Studio 2022: How to disable/change 'Match whole word (Alt+W)' keyboard shortcut

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 IDE in Quick Find pane there is an option to match whole words. I keep enabling it (Alt+W opens Window menu, but does not work when in Quick Find pane).

[image: Quick Find pane]

I cannot find it anywhere in customization options. Is there a way to disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be customizable.  You *can* change the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut however for the toolbar.

The toolbar logic is similar to when you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> in other applications like Microsoft Office or Outlook (so called "[ribbon shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_ribbonwin)" as Microsoft calls them).  To change this in Visual Studio, go to Tools → Customize. Then select the Commands tab and scroll the inner menu down to Window.  Click on "Window" and then click the "Modify Selection" button.  A new prompt will open to allow you to rename the Command to whatever you wish.  In my example, I added a "Q" to the end of the word "Window" and then put an `&` in front of the Q.  The `&` dictates that the letter following it is used for the shortcut.

[image: customizing commands]

Now, when I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the "Q" is underlined, denoting that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> would trigger the shortcut now:

[image: alt q shortcut for window command]

I figured <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> would be the best shortcut to change it to in this case because the "Q" key is right next to the "W" key on the keyboard, the muscle memory shouldn't be too much of an issue.  Obviously you are free to make it whatever you wish!
Additionally, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't seem to be mapped to anything by default.  The only drawback is now your "Window" command looks a little uglier in the toolbar with a random looking "Q".

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I have muscle memory of Alt+W after using it for 20+ years, wonder if I will be able to reprogram my hand :)